# Reactive list using v-for on component

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am using vue.js class style with vue-property-decorator plugin.
i have a class called Person like below:

```
export default class Person {

   fullName: string = '';
   id: number = 0;
   isSelected: boolean = false;
}
```

and two components: PersonList and PersonSingle that PersonList shows a list of PersonSingles using v-for and passing Person object;

here is the PersonSingle:

```
<template>
<div :class="{selected:isSelected}" @click="select" 
style="margin:20px;border:1px solid green;">
   <h1>{{fullName}}</h1> 
</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {Vue, Component, Prop} from 'vue-property-decorator';
import Person from '@/store/person';
@Component({})
export default class PersonSingle extends Vue {
@Prop() data?: Person;
fullName: string = '';
isSelected: boolean = false;
id: number = 0;

created(){
    if(this.data === null || this.data === undefined) return;
    this.fullName = this.data.fullName;
    this.isSelected = this.data.isSelected;
    this.id = this.data.id;
}

select(){
    this.$emit('PersonSelected',this.id);
}

}
</script>

<style>
    .selected{
        color:red;
        background-color: darkgray;
    }
</style>
```

and the PersonList:

```
<template>
 <div>
    <PersonSingle
    v-for="(person,index) in persons" 
    :key="person.id"  
    :index="index"
    :data="person"
    @PersonSelected="onPersonSelected($event)"
    ></PersonSingle>
   </div>
   </template>
   <script lang="ts">
   import {Vue, Component, Prop} from 'vue-property-decorator';
   import PersonSingle from '@/components/PersonSingle.vue'
   import Person from '@/store/person'
   import {ObservableArray} from '@/store/person';
   @Component({
   components: {PersonSingle}
   })
   export default class PersonList extends Vue {

  persons: Person[] = [] ;
  created(){
    const p1 = new Person();
    p1.fullName = "Mohsen Seylani";
    p1.id = 1;
    p1.isSelected = true;
    const p2 = new Person();
    p2.fullName = "Hassan Najrani";
    p2.id = 2;
    const p3 = new Person();
    p3.fullName = "Reza Rad";
    p3.id = 3;
    const tempArray: Person[] = [];
    this.persons.push(p1,p2,p3);

}
onPersonSelected(id: number){
    let index = 0;
    let tempPerson = new Person();
    this.persons.forEach((item,i)=>{
        item.isSelected = false;
        if(item.id === id){
            index = i;
            tempPerson = item;
        }
    });
    tempPerson.isSelected = true;
    this.$set(this.persons,index,tempPerson);

    }
    }
   </script>
```

the output is like below:
[image]

i want when user clicks one of PersonSingle that item be selected and others be deselected. as codes are saying i used this.$set to change the value of isSelected property of object.
but this code does not work and list no be rerendered.

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't like Screenshots. Please read the ["How do I ask?" Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it is clearly saying: " **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `isSelected` in `PersonSingle` but only assign to it on `created` hook which is never called again after component creation. Either do the assignments in a watcher for `data` inside `PersonSingle`, or eliminate `isSelected` altogether and use `data.isSelected` directly as `isSelected` is kinda redundant in this example.

Comment: Using data.isSelected directly works well.thank you!